# Assertion is failing before the timeout is complete

Tags: typescript, playwright

It seems like these lines fail before the 3 minutes, I've set are up.

`await expect(this.uploadModal).toBeHidden({ timeout: 180000 });`

`await expect(this.pdfSuccessfullyRendered.nth(0)).toBeVisible({ timeout: 180000 });`

I have to set an unusually large timeout for these specific elements because its dealing with uploading a file to the application,
I've tried changing the expect timeout in the config to 180000 for a more global approach,

```
 globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),
  expect: {timeout:180000},
  use: {
    baseURL: process.env.URL, 
    headless: true
  },
```

as well as changing the test timeout to 180000 in the before each hook but it still fails around 30 seconds.

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
       test.setTimeout(180000);
    });
```

```
Error: expect(received).toBeHidden()
    Call log:
      - expect.toBeHidden with timeout 180000ms
      - waiting for selector "//app-upload-document"
      -   selector resolved to <app-upload-document _nghost-vih-c387="" class="ng-star-inserted">…</app-upload-document>
      -   unexpected value "false"
      -   selector resolved to <app-upload-document _nghost-vih-c387="" class="ng-star-inserted">…</app-upload-document>
      -   unexpected value "false"
```

Im not sure what the error is about, as that specific element is interacted with before I wait for it to become hidden so I know it exists on the page, it ends up disappearing once the document is fully uploaded, after which the page auto navigates and I start waiting for the document to start loading

`await expect(this.pdfSuccessfullyRendered.nth(0)).toBeVisible({ timeout: 180000 });`

I can see the timeout in the console on the exception but the test isnt waiting the 3 minutes before failing, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value returned from `jest.setTimeout` for it to do anything:

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  return test.setTimeout(180000);
});
```

Comment: I will give this a try thank you

Comment: I believe this solved the issue, my tests are completing beyond the 30 seconds timeout now, thank you.